# PhoneGap's FileTransfert Success Callback error

Tags: cordova, file-transfer

I'm using PhonGap's FileTransfert method like so

```
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
        //options.chunkedMode = true;

        var params = new Object();
        params.title = title;
        params.content = content;
        params.groupId = groupId;

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        app.loadmask.show();
        ft.upload(app.imageURI, app.stores.actionAjaxURL + "&cmd=addActualite", this.onSuccessCreateActualite, this.onFailureCreateActualite, options, true);
```

This goes to the success callback function which is :

```
onSuccessCreateActualite: function(response, options) {
        /* REINIT FORM VALUES */
        app.imageURI = null;
        console.log("This log appears");
        this.titleField.reset();
        console.log("This log does not appear");
        this.groupSelect.reset();
        this.contentField.reset();
        this.addBtn.resumeEvents();
        this.picturePnl.update("No Picture");

        app.stores.actualites.load();
        app.loadmask.hide();
        app.views.viewport.actualites.setActiveItem(
            app.views.viewport.actualites.actualitesList, {type:'slide', direction:'right'}
        );

        app.views.viewport.actualites.actualitesList.actuGrid.scroller.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 0 });
},
```

And I'm getting this error :

**Error in success callback: com.phonegap.filetransfer1 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object**

Does anyone knows why ?

Thanks

Comment: try including the options.fileName option

Comment: But the fileTransfert works (I can see the picture on my server). The error has something to do with the this.titleField.reset();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "this.titleField" is out of scope in your onSuccessCreateActualite function. Most probably "this" is referring to a different object then you think it is. I'd inspect what the properties of "this" are to see what it actually refers to.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with my scope. Try calling the function like this:

```
this.onSuccessCreateActualite.bind(this)
```

in your `upload()` method.